# shell script to move data from other server's (or nodes) sub-dirs to current server(node) matching sub-dir

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've .parquet files for multiple dates *(from 20190927 to 20200131)* inside `/data/pg/export/schema.table_YYYYMMDD<random alphanumric string>` directory structure in seven different nodes. `When process ran, it created sub-directory in schema.table_YYYYMMDD<random alphanumric string> format` *(such as schema.table_20190927)* `inside /data/pg/export path for each date`. However, it did append some random letter on sub-dir on other hosts. So for instance, I've folder, files in following format:

**on node#1 (10.245.122.100)**

`/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927` contains:

```
----1.parquet
----2.parquet
----3.parquet
```

**on node#2 (10.245.122.101)**

`/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927S8rW4dQ2` contains:

```
----4.parquet
----5.parquet
----6.parquet
```

**on node#3 (10.245.122.102)**

`/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927P5SJ9aX4` contains:

```
----7.parquet
----8.parquet
----9.parquet
```

and so on for other nodes.

How I can bring files from `/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927S8rW4dQ2 on node#2 (10.245.122.101)` and `/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927P5SJ9aX4 on node#3 (10.245.122.102)` (and similar for other hosts) to `/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927 on node#1 (10.245.122.100)` so

```
final output look like:

***on node#1 (10.245.122.100)***

/data/pg/export/schema.table_20190927 will have:

    ----1.parquet
    ----2.parquet
    ----3.parquet
    ----4.parquet
    ----5.parquet
    ----6.parquet
    ----7.parquet
    ----8.parquet
    ----9.parquet
```

Comment: Before posting another question, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  Since it is your first question (well the first I see), and I liked the challenge, here is a script that will do that.  For your next question, you must provide your own code with a specific problem you are having, and not expect a complete script as an answer.  See my comment for stuff to read on using SO.

The bash knowledge required to make this work is:

- while loop
- date calculation
- variable value incrementation (so basic math)

I made some assumptions:

- you have a single user on all nodes which can be used to do `scp` from node1
- that user is hopefully setup to use ssh keys to login, otherwise you will type your password **a lot** of times!
- you have connected at least 1 time to each node, and they are listed in your known_hosts file
- on each node, there is 1 **and only one** directory with a specific date in the name.
- all files are copied in each directory.  You can modify the `scp` command to get only the `.parquet` files if you want.

Basic ideas in the code

- loop on each node, so from 2 to 7
- loop on dates, so from 20190927 to 20200131
- copy files for each node, each date within the loops
- this was tested on Linux Mint (== Ubuntu) so the `date` command is the gnu version, which allows for date calculation the way I did it.

Before use, modify the value of the `user` variable with your user name.

*DISCLAIMER*: I did not have multiple systems to test the `scp` command, so this command was added by memory.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script runs on node1
# The node1 IP is 10.245.122.100
#
# This script assumes that you want to copy all files under
# /data/pg/export/schema.table_YYYMMDD<random>
#
###############################################################################

# node1 variables
targetdirprefix="/data/pg/export/schema.table_"
user="YOURUSER"

# Other nodes variables
total_number_nodes=7        # includes node1
ip_prefix=10.245.122
ip_lastdigit_start=99       # node1 == 100, so start at 99

# loop on nodes ---------------------------------------------------------------

# start at node 2, node1 is the target node
nodecount=2
# Stop at maxnode+1, here he last node will be 7
(( whileexit = total_number_nodes + 1 ))

while [[ "$nodecount" -lt "$whileexit" ]]
do
    # build the current node IP
    (( currentnode_lastdigit = ip_lastdigit_start + nodecount ))
    currentnode_ip="${ip_prefix}.${currentnode_lastdigit}"

    # DEBUG
    echo "nodecount=$nodecount, ip=$currentnode_ip"

    # loop on dates ---------------------------------------
    firstdate="20190927"
    lastdate="20200131"

    loopdate="$firstdate"
    while [[ "$loopdate" -le "$lastdate" ]]
    do
        # DEBUG
        echo "loopdate=$loopdate"

        # go into the target directory (create it if required)
        targetdir="${targetdirprefix}${loopdate}"
        if [[ -d "$targetdir" ]]
        then
            cd "$targetdir"
        else
            mkdir -p "$targetdir"
            if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]
            then
                echo "ERROR: could not create directory $targetdir, exiting."
                exit 1
            else
                cd "$targetdir"
            fi
        fi

        # copy the date's file into the target dir (i.e. localy, since we did a cd before)
        # the source directory is the same as the targetdir, with extra chars at the end
        # this script assumes there is only 1 directory with that particular date!
        scp ${user}@${currentnode_ip}:${targetdir}* .
        if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]
        then
            echo "WARNING: copy failed from node $nodecount, date $loopdate."
            echo "         The script will continue for other dates and nodes..."
        fi

        loopdate=$(date --date "$loopdate +1 days" +%Y%m%d)
    done

    (( nodecount += 1 ))

done
```